# Ruby 2 Keyword Arguments and ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails 4 application that is running on ruby 2.1. I have a `User` model that looks something like

```
class User < ActiveModel::Base
  def self.search(query: false, active: true, **extra)
    # ...
  end
end
```

As you can see in the search method I am attempting to use the new keyword arguments feature of ruby 2.

The problem is that when I call this code from in my controller all values get dumped into `query`.

**params**

```
{"action"=>"search", "controller"=>"users", query: "foobar" }
```

*Please note that this is a ActionController::Parameters object and not a hash as it looks*

**UsersController**

```
def search
  @users = User.search(params)
end
```

I feel that this is because params is a `ActionController::Parameters` object and not a hash. However even calling `to_h` on params when passing it in dumps everything into `query` instead of the expected behavior. I think this is because the keys are now strings instead of symbols.

I know that I could build a new hash w/ symbols as the keys but this seems to be more trouble than it's worth. Ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: posting the content your `params` would help

Comment: @bjhaid Updated w/ contents of `params`

Answer (score 9):

Keywords arguments must be passed as hash with symbols, not strings:

```
class Something
  def initialize(one: nil)
  end
end

irb(main):019:0> Something.new("one" => 1)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

`ActionController::Parameters` inherits from `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` which defaults to string keys:

```
a = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(one: 1)
=> {"one"=>1}
```

To make it symbols you can call `symbolize_keys` method. In your case: `User.search(params.symbolize_keys)`

Comment: There is an issue opened on rails tracker: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14643

Comment: In Ruby 2.2, doing Something.new("one": 1) will work, so the issue is not symbol vs string. Using '=>' vs ':' seems to make the difference. Using .to_h on the object before you pass the parameter will fix the problem.

Comment: @WinstonKotzan I think you misunderstand the 2.2 syntax. `Something.new("one": 1)` is creating a hash using a symbol key, not a string key. Try `Something.new("one" => 1)` on 2.2 and you'll get the same error. So you do need `symbolize_keys`.

Comment: I had to combine answers: params.to_h.symbolize_keys did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Morgoth, however, with rails ~5 you will get a Deprecation Warning because ActionController::Parameters no longer inherits from hash.  So instead you can do:

```
params.to_unsafe_hash.symbolize_keys
```

or if you have nested params as is often the case when building api endpoints:

```
params.to_unsafe_hash.deep_symbolize_keys
```

You might add a method to ApplicationController that looks something like this:

```
def unsafe_keyworded_params
  @_unsafe_keyworded_params ||= params.to_unsafe_hash.deep_symbolized_keys
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do need them to be symbols. Try this:

```
def search
  @users = User.search(params.inject({}){|para,(k,v)| para[k.to_sym] = v; para}
end
```

I know it's not the ideal solution, but it is a one liner.

Comment: I guess this is what `User.search(params.to_h)` would do as the OP claimed he has done

Comment: @bjhaid This does something slightly different than `to_h`. This makes the keys symbols whereas `to_h` makes the keys strings (which apparently breaks keyword arguments).

Comment: as referenced [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/83#issuecomment-14935519) if it's a string it will stay a string. My code converts the first string to a Symbol, which is most likely what ruby is looking for.

Comment: @snowe2010 This solution does in fact work but I feel that it greatly outweighs the benefits of keyword arguments :(

Comment: Ah, if it's not a hash I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: @KyleDecot Yes, it does. You could do what Jon has suggested and try to monkey patch the `ActionController::Parameters` class to add the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance I think you're better off passing the params object and treating it as such rather than trying to be clever with the new functionality in Ruby 2.

For one thing, reading this is a lot clearer about where the variables are coming from and why they might be missing/incorrect/whatever:

```
def search(params)
  raise ArgumentError, 'Required arguments are missing' unless params[:query].present?

  # ... do stuff ...
end
```

What you're trying to do (in my opinion) only clouds the issue and confuses things when trying to debug problems:

```
def self.search(query: false, active: true, **extra)
  # ...
end

# Method explicitly asks for particular arguments, but then you call it like this:
User.search(params)
```

Personally, I think that code is a bit smelly.

However ... personal opinion aside, how I would fix it would be to monkey-patch the ActionController::Parameters class and add a `#to_h` method which structured the data as you need it to pass to a method like this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `to_unsafe_hash` is unsafe because it includes params that are not permitted. (See [ActionController::Parameters#permit](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)) A better approach is to use `to_hash`:

```
params.to_hash.symbolize_keys
```

or if you have nested params:

```
params.to_hash.deep_symbolize_keys
```

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_hash